# libreoffice calc: Importing csv full of URL's

Tags: libreoffice, url, csv

I'm importing a CSV full of date, time, URI, etc., into LibreOffice Calc.  I'd like the URIs (which point to documents) to be imported as click-able links, but the Fields > Column-Type drop-down on the import dialogue doesn't give that option.  Otherwise, I'd like to be able to change the full imported column into hyperlinks, rather than being forced to do it one cell at a time, as with Insert > Hyperlink.

The URI could either look like `file:///document-path` or just the path/filename.  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, I got an answer.  You need to just find and replace (under Edit):

```
http:.*|file:.*
```

with:

```
=HYPERLINK("&","Some text here")
```

Then check the box for: "regular expression" and finally, "replace all".

`"Some text here"` could be another `"&"` if you just want to keep the visible text the same, but turn it into a link.

(Thanks to pierre-yves samyn)